# Is there a trick to correctly defining version properties in NHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am trying to use NHibernate to map a legacy database which uses a `decimal(9,0)` (~32 bit integer) "version property" (for optimistic locking of each row).

The fields are declared nullable in the database, and in section 5.1.7 of the NHibernate reference manual it states:

> Version numbers may be of type Int64, Int32, Int16, Ticks, Timestamp, or TimeSpan (or their nullable counterparts
>   in .NET 2.0).

... so I mapped them as `int?` version properties.

My mapping document looks similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping namespace="Model" assembly="Model" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
    <class name="Bar" lazy="true" table="`BAR`" schema="`dbo`">
        <id name="ID" access="property" column="`ID`">
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <version name="Version" column="`VERSION`" type="int?" />
        <!-- ... etc ... -->
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

However, at runtime, this fails miserably with an exception similar to:

```
failed: NHibernate.MappingException : Could not compile the mapping document: Model.Mappings.Bar.hbm.xml
  ----> NHibernate.MappingException : Could not determine type for: Model.int?,  for columns: NHibernate.Mapping.Column(VERSION)
    at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.LogAndThrow(Exception exception)
    at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddValidatedDocument(NamedXmlDocument doc)
    at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.ProcessMappingsQueue()
    at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddDocumentThroughQueue(NamedXmlDocument document)
    at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddXmlReader(XmlReader hbmReader, String name)
    at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddInputStream(Stream xmlInputStream, String name)
    at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddResource(String path, Assembly assembly)
    at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddAssembly(Assembly assembly)
    Core\DAOUtils.cs(33,0): at Core.DAOUtils.OpenSession()
    test\cs\FooTest.cs(65,0): at DataModel.Tests.FooTest.TestSelectStar()
    --MappingException
    at NHibernate.Mapping.SimpleValue.get_Type()
    at NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.RootClassBinder.BindProperty(HbmVersion versionSchema, Property property, IDictionary`2 inheritedMetas)
    at NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.RootClassBinder.BindVersion(HbmVersion versionSchema, PersistentClass rootClass, Table table, IDictionary`2 inheritedMetas)
    at NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.RootClassBinder.Bind(XmlNode node, HbmClass classSchema, IDictionary`2 inheritedMetas)
    at NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.MappingRootBinder.AddRootClasses(XmlNode parentNode, IDictionary`2 inheritedMetas)
    at NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.MappingRootBinder.Bind(XmlNode node)
    at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddValidatedDocument(NamedXmlDocument doc)
```

Is there some trick to correctly using version properties with NHibernate, or am I doing something wrong?

One odd thing to me is that NHibernate seems to be appending my assembly/namespace name to the beginning of the `int?` type, which seems wrong.

**Edit:**

After changing the mapping files to use `int` instead of `int?` I am now hitting the following exception:

```
System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type 'NHibernate.Type.DecimalType' to type 'NHibernate.Type.IVersionType'.
    at NHibernate.Tuple.PropertyFactory.BuildVersionProperty(Property property, Boolean lazyAvailable)
    at NHibernate.Tuple.Entity.EntityMetamodel..ctor(PersistentClass persistentClass, ISessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory)
    at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister..ctor(PersistentClass persistentClass, ICacheConcurrencyStrategy cache, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
    at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.SingleTableEntityPersister..ctor(PersistentClass persistentClass, ICacheConcurrencyStrategy cache, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory, IMapping mapping)
    at NHibernate.Persister.PersisterFactory.CreateClassPersister(PersistentClass model, ICacheConcurrencyStrategy cache, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory, IMapping cfg)
    at NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl..ctor(Configuration cfg, IMapping mapping, Settings settings, EventListeners listeners)
    at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSessionFactory()
```

Unfortunately, NHibernate isn't giving me a very detailed error message here (it would be nice to know which class out of the hundreds of classes is throwing this), and I haven't been able to convince log4net to work, so I'm at a loss for the moment.

**Edit #2:**

To summarize the "tricks":

- Assuming integer version properties, (and even if they are declared `decimal` in the database) make sure all version properties are declared as `int` in the mapping XML. (though it should work if `int?` is declared in the POCO)
- Make sure no version properties are set as a `decimal` type (either in the POCOs or the mapping XML)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't include the '?' in the mapping - instead write type="Int32". If your property in your POCO is nullable it should work out fine. (At least it does for properties - I haven't tried having a nullable version column...).

Comment: Thanks; very helpful. That got me past the original exception. Now I'm hitting a different one. (question updated)

Comment: I think I misread your question... are you using decimal as the type in the version-column? Type decimal is not supported as a version column (hence the - cannot cast to IVersionType-exception).

Comment: Yes and no... yes, in that I am mapping a legacy database whose version properties are defined as "decimal(9,0)". (I can't change the schema.) No, in that I am trying to map them all as 32-bit integers. Not sure why this wouldn't work, except that if I get version numbers above 999,999,999 the database may complain.

Comment: The problem is that NHibernate when reading from the Database gets a decimal (as it should) and a decimal cannot be a version-column. NHibernate only supports whole numbers in the database column as well as the property in your POCO.

Comment: Sadly, I believe you need to handle versioning manually by putting it into a normal decimal property and then handling the concurrency in an interceptor.

Comment: @Goblin, are you certain? Because it looks like NHibernate is throwing this exception before it even tries to read from the database; it's only opening the session. (I guess maybe by this time it's already talking to the database and comparing notes on its idea of the schema vs. the real database...)

Comment: You are correct - I didn't look closely at the stacktrace. It is indeed when creating the sessionfactory - what is the type of the property in the POCO? (NHibernate creates a proxy of each mapped POCO to check that it is possible when creating the sessionfactory.

Comment: @Goblin, on my first pass, all the POCO properties were type "int?". Since I had lingering doubts about this not matching the XML mappings, I since changed them to "int". (no change; same error)

Comment: Hmm... from the error - it seems that one of your POCOs has a decimal property set as the version property... I'm about fresh out of ideas if that isn't the case.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, it wasn't quite that. I had the wrong column set to the version property in one of the mapping .xml files, and it happened to be a decimal column. After I fixed that, it worked! Thanks for all your help.